# is there a way to extract duplicated row value in sql as the key/grouping value?

Tags: sql, node.js, sqlite, join, group-concat

I have following two tables

users

```
id | name

1  | john
2  | ada
```

events

```
id |   content   | userId

1  | 'applied'   | 1
2  | 'interviewed| 1
```

What would be the query that returns data in the following shape:

```
[
  {name:'john', events:[{id:1, content:'applied'},{id:2, content:'interviewed'}]}
]
```

I have tried to run following queries

attempt 1

```
select events.id, content, users.name 
from events 
left join users 
on users.id=events.userId 
where events.userId = ?
```

but it return duplicated value for the name as following

```
[
{
"id": 1,
"content": "ronaldo",
"name": "Norman Zboncak"
},
{
"id": 2,
"content": "messi",
"name": "Norman Zboncak"
},
{
"id": 3,
"content": "messi",
"name": "Norman Zboncak"
}
]
```

attempt 2

I tried to use `group_concat` but apparently you cannot pas multiple arguments into it so couldn't get the result in the desired shape

Comment: I don't think this can be done in one query, unless you process data afterwards. Your desired result is 1:N for each user. The query result would be line-based, for each event. Can't you run another query for each user ?

Comment: How would i do it?

Answer (score 0):

You must do a `LEFT` join of users to events and aggregate with [SQLite's JSON Functions](https://www.sqlite.org/json1.html):

```
SELECT json_object(
          'name', u.name, 
          'events', json_group_array(json_object('id', e.id, 'content', e.content))
       ) result
FROM users u LEFT JOIN events e
ON e.userId = u.id  
WHERE u.id = 1 -- remove this line to get results for all users
GROUP BY u.id;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=d16651e3eb12815a4f46c2f07d866808).

Comment: thank you. is json_object similar to group_concat in that it is a function that you can pass arguments into? what would be a good source to read more on json_object to see other practical examples?

Comment: @esentai here: https://www.sqlite.org/json1.html you can find more about JSON functions of SQLite. group_concat() is an aggregate function that works with any type of data and returns strings, but what your expected results are structured json data.